# Calling web service through jQuery and passing object to rest web service which accepts java object

Tags: java, jquery, date

My web service is working fine when I am testing it through rest client
but when I try to call it through jQuery it fails . the main problem is basically with serialization of JSON data into the object.

My web service is like this

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({"userId":124,"emailId":"ranjeet@triconinfotec.com","role":"instrutor","date":"2014-08-01","target":"Section",
                    "sectionId":234,"sectionName":"Economics","assignmentId":9991,"assignmentName":"EZT","isbn":"124XSD234","courseId":33,
                    "courseName":"GeneralEconomics","ipaddress":"192.168.1.210","pageId":"sd345"}),                                 

                url: "http://localhost:7001/connect/restservices/insight/assignmentgraph/connecttrack/activity",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(){  
                    // we have the response  
                    alert("Success");  
                  },  
                  error: function(e){  
                    alert('Error: ' + e);  
                  }
```

This web service get called but its goes to error and display error [object object].

I think the problem is with serialization date in the content because in my Java file this class date has a date type instead of string.

Answer (score 0):

Change the error handler as below, and then investigate the response:

```
error: function(x, e) {  
   alert('Status code: ' + x.status + ', Error: ' + e);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your web service needs to know how to convert a String to a Date.  You didn't mention what framework you're using on the server to create your web service, but I imagine it has the ability to setup a converter.  If not, a quick and dirty work around would be to change the type of your field to String, and then once the request from the client comes in, use something like SimpleDateFormat to parse the String into a Date and store it in another field.